# Dragging/Dropping multiple views simultaneously in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, drag-and-drop, multiple-instances

I've been following Bill Lahti's excellent tutorials on [Drag n Drop in a Grid View](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/). I would like to know how to extend this framework to drag and drop multiple views together.

In my project I can drag and drop letters to the grid cells. I would like to allow connected letter-chains (words) to be moved together as well. But I am not sure how to achieve this.